# How to setup ReactNative ScrollView for different devices viewports?

Tags: android, react-native

Per documentation [here](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#content), ReactNative ScrollView must have bounded height in order to work. However, the height varies by the device, one size doesn't fit all. Is there anyway to set the height device agnostic?

Answer (score 1):

React Native provides a 'Dimensions' object that allows you to get the window width and height (among other things). You can pull the window (which would be the screen size) width and height and do with it as you please.

```
var Dimensions = require('Dimensions');
Dimensions.get('window').width;
Dimensions.get('window').height;
```

Comment: Thanks, will try that.